# Show attribute in a particular category products in Magento admin

Tags: magento, attributes, magento-1.9, custom-attributes

I want to show an attribute to a particular category products as it is not useful for other category products. There are specific attributes define for each category products and all attributes are different for each category products.

So, I don't want to show all attributes in all products. I just want to show those attributes which is required for a particular category products. Is there any way to define attribute as per category wise products?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an option:

1. Created a new attribute set based on default attribute set.
2. Assign your desired attribute into the new attribute set.
3. Select new created attribute set during the product add.

You can use this new created attribute set for your targeted categories.

Comment: Please read the question carefully.......I know how to add attribute from admin and use it in front end. But i want to show an attribute for few products only not to all products

Answer (score 0):

You can write this code in your view.phtml file.

```
<?php
    $product_id = $_product->getId();
    $your_custom_product_id = array('51','52','53','54','55','56'); // Your customs Product Ids
    
    if(in_array($product_id,$your_custom_product_id)) {
        $attribute = $_product->getResource()->getAttribute(‘attribute_code’);
        echo $attribute->getFrontendLabel();
        echo $attributeValue = Mage::getModel(‘catalog/product’)->load($_product->getId())->getMyAttribute();
    }
?>
```

Comment: The above code is to show in frontend but i want that attribute show in admin as per category wise for a particular product.....Not in every products